# Decreasing log level in Eclipse WTP with Tomcat 7

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, logging, eclipse-wtp

I am running Tomcat 7 from within Eclipse WTP (Juno) and I cannot seem to tune down the logging level. It logs everything from debug which is too verbose to be of any use (I want it log from INFO). The logging.properties file is as follows:

```
handlers =  java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level=INFO

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.  
############################################################

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same problem with my eclipse + wtp ...

Answer (score 9):

Adding **both** of these per the [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#How_do_I_enable_the_JULI_logging_in_a_Tomcat_5.5_Server_instance.3F) that Tom Chatt cites:

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="${workspace_loc}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf/logging.properties"
```

to the arguments to the server's launch configuration will get you what you want.
`${workspace_loc}` is literal; Eclipse will substitute it with your workspace directory.
`tmp0` may be `tmp1` or such instead; use the same path that's in the server's configuration.
Assumes that you've placed the `logging.properties` file there, of course.
That way you'll see the file in the Project Explorer window under Servers.
You should start by copying the one from the Tomcat `conf` directory.

This all assumes that you're intent on using JULI.

Works for me with Tomcat 8.0 and Eclipse Mars.
No idea why it didn't work for Tom.
I did see `ClassNotFound`s, for the obvious reason, when I used the wrong class name from someone's post.

I'd advise against the approach of Tom Chatt, since that will affect all of the other uses of that JVM.

Comment: this is a better answer.  this is basically a bug as this should be the default behaviour for a tomcat server on wtp

Comment: I only had to add "-Djava.util.logging.config.file=..." with a small tweak (in my case I had "tmp1" as I had multiple server instances configured) and it worked. I did not have to add "-Djava.util.logging.manager". Just like the comment above I fail to understand why this is not a part of default configuration.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue, wanting to configure the logging levels of Tomcat 7 in Eclipse WTP. I tried putting a logging.properties in the /src directory of my web app. No effect. I tried modifying the logging.properties file in the /conf directory of my Tomcat installation, but no effect there either. I discovered Eclipse WTP's "shadow" Tomcat area, under my workspace directory, in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0, and put a logging.properties file in the /conf directory under there. No effect.

I discovered a number of articles (e.g., [this FAQ at eclipse.org](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#How_do_I_enable_the_JULI_logging_in_a_Tomcat_5.5_Server_instance.3F)) noting that while Tomcat in "real life" automatically runs with a logging manager called "JULI", for some reason the Tomcat running inside Eclipse WTP does not run with JULI. I tried adding

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
```

to the VM args in my Tomcat run config, but that just got me ClassNotFound errors. (And yes, I did have tomcat-juli.jar in my classpath, so no idea why it wasn't finding it.)

Finally, it occurred to me to try modifying the logging.properties instance in my jdk jre/lib. Jackpot! It turns out that's the one that does have an effect on the logging done by Tomcat-in-Eclipse. So, the moral of this long tale is that if all you want to do is just simply configure the logging while you're running in Eclipse, with a simple little statement like:

```
myapp.mypackage.level=FINE
```

Then $JAVAHOME/lib/logging.properties is the place to put it.

Comment: Plus make sure the corresponding root level and ConsoleAppender levels do not filter it out, i.e. `.level=FINE` and `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I followed the tomcat log4j guide at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html. This will make tomcat use log4j.

Next set up a log4j config in $CATALINA_HOME/lib.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">


   <appender name="null" class="org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender" />

   <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<category name="org.package.domain">
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
 </category>

 </log4j:configuration>
```