# Tomcat 8 won't start

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, logging, tomcat8, tomcat-juli

I've been searching quite a bit, but can't find the answer. I just upgraded STS (from 3.2) so I could try out Tomcat 8 (from 7.0.53). I've got STS 3.6.2 and Tomcat 8.0.15. After adding the TC8 server and configuring it it refuses to start, with this root error:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.WebappProperties`

So I read up quite a bit and found [this guide](http://ci.apache.org/projects/tomcat/tomcat8/docs/logging.html) to switching from hard-coded commons-logging via Juli to Log4J and followed it to the letter without any luck. A relevant excerpt:

> The internal logging for Apache Tomcat uses JULI, a packaged renamed
>   fork of Apache Commons Logging that, by default, is hard-coded to use
>   the java.util.logging framework. This ensures that Tomcat's internal
>   logging and any web application logging will remain independent, even
>   if a web application uses Apache Commons Logging.
>
> To configure Tomcat to use an alternative logging framework for its internal logging, one has to replace the JULI impementation that
>   is hard-coded to use java.util.logging with a JULI implementation that
>   retains the full Commons Logging discovery mechanism. Such an
>   implementation is provided as an extras component. Instructions on how
>   to configure Tomcat to use Log4j framework for its internal logging
>   may be found below.

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24095097/375399) (to a different question) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166414/local-tomcat-environment-not-starting) from here, where the latter appears to have a nearly identical problem without any solution.

I've searched all JARs in my Tomcat's bin/lib folders and found no such class (including various versions of `tomcat-juli.jar` and `tomcat-juli-adapters.jar`). I find barely any reference on the internet to this class/interface except on the Tomcat 8 Logging guide linked earlier. So, the question is: Why is Tomcat looking for this class?

Again from the linked guide, here's what it says:

> **If using a class loader that implements the
>   `org.apache.juli.WebappProperties` interface (Tomcat's web application
>   class loader does)** then property replacement is also performed for
>   `${classloader.webappName}`, `${classloader.hostName}` and
>   `${classloader.serviceName}` which are replaced with the web application
>   name, the host name and the service name respectively.

Why is my Tomcat class loader not actually implementing that then, or why isn't it finding it?

Comment: I added Eclipse as a tag since the Tomcat server adapter comes from the Eclipse Webtools project - which is pre-installed in STS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our Ant Tomcat configuration process copied Tomcat 7's tomcat-juli.jar over to Tomcat 8, causing the issue.

Getting the correct tomcat-juli.jar for Tomcat 8 from Apache's Tomcat Extras section fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That interface is in tomcat-juli.jar and Tomcat's web application class loader implements that interface.

You do not need to switch to log4j based logging to fix this issue.

tomcat-juli.jar (which should be in the bin directory) appears to be missing from a class path somewhere. Not sure if this is configuration error on your part of something that needs tweaking Eclipse's integration for Apache Tomcat.

I suggest you start with a clean Tomcat 8.0.15 install from the ASF, make sure that works from the command line and then try integrating that with STS/Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Check the version on Tomcat that you're using. We expect Tomcat 8.5.4 or higher by default now. If you want to use an older version you'll need to add tomcat-juli as documented in the release notes